# Ajax find by value

Tags: ajax, find

I wish to find a div by html value.

```
<div class="myClass">
    <div class="title">
        <div class="text">blue</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="myClass">
    <div class="title">
        <div class="text">red</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="myClass">
    <div class="title">
        <div class="text">yellow</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Class are the same and i wish to hide only the "myClass div" that have "red" in html value.

Do you know how to find "Red" via Ajax?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need Ajax to do this, you can simply loop through the divs:

```js
$('.myClass').find('div').children('.text').each((i,e)=>{
if($.trim($(e)[0].textContent).toLowerCase() == "red"){
$(e).css("color","red");
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass">
    <div class="title">
        <div class="text">blue</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="myClass">
    <div class="title">
        <div class="text">red</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="myClass">
    <div class="title">
        <div class="text">yellow</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Great ! Thank you for your help :)